# Why this object method can get the value of an external function?

Tags: javascript

```
function Counter() {
  let count = 0;       //Without 'this'
 
  this.up = function() {
    return ++count;
  };
  this.down = function() {
    return --count;
  };
}
 
let counter = new Counter();
counter.up()  //1，Why the method still got the value of count?
```

In my understanding, the object `counter` has 2 methods (up & down), and NO `count`, like this:

```
counter={
    up(){
        return ++count;
    },
    down(){
        return --count;
    }
}
```

Wondering why running counter.up() still got the value of `count`?

Comment: Closures. Basically.

Answer (score 0):

the JavaScript features closures working here. which makes it to contain value of outside variables using inline function.